# TypeScript: Why is Parameters generic accepting incorrect arguments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a function with defined types for arguments. The arguments are `key`, which is a key of a specified interface `IBook`, and `value` which should have the type corresponding to that specific key in the interface. I.e. if `key === 'id'` then the only accepted type for `value` should be `number`.

The problem arises when I want to create another function to just pass arguments from `onChange` event to the first one. To avoid re-declaring function arguments again, I used `Parameters` generic, but it seems to behave incorrectly. Check the usage below.

```
interface IBook {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  isPromoted?: boolean;
}

export const editBook = <K extends keyof Required<IBook>>(
  key: K,
  value: Required<IBook>[K],
) => ({
  type: 'EDIT_BOOK',
  payload: { key, value },
});

const onChange = (...args: Parameters<typeof editBook>) => {
  dispatch(editBook(...args));
};

editBook('id', 'some string'); // string not accepted here, shows error
onChange('id', 'some string'); // no error here

editBook('id', true); // boolean not accepted here, shows error
onChange('id', true); // no error here
```

If I use the original function `editBook`, then `value` is typed correctly - it's only the one corresponding to the type of `key`. If I use another one, an error is shown. However, if I use the wrapper function `onChange`, then any type existing in `IBook` is accepted for `value` argument.

Any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Parameters` you don't capture the type parameters of the original function, typescript will just use the constraint where it finds any reference to the type parameter so the signature of `onChange` will actually just be:

```
(key: keyof IBook, value: Required<IBook>[keyof IBook]) => void
```

which will work out to:

```
(key: "id" | "title" | "isPromoted", value: string | number | boolean) => void
```

allowing the invalid calls.

There is unfortunately no explicit way to capture type parameters and forward them to the new function. Starting in 3.4, there is an implicit way to do this, using a pipe function as [described here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215)

```
function pipe<A extends any[], B, C>(ab: (...args: A) => B, bc: (b: B) => C): (...args: A) => C {
    return (...args: A) => bc(ab(...args));
}

function dispatch<T extends { type: string }>(action: T): void {

}
const onChange = pipe(editBook, dispatch); // generic type parameter preserved

editBook('id', 'some string'); // string not accepted here, shows error
onChange('id', 'some string'); // error now

editBook('id', true); // boolean not accepted here, shows error
onChange('id', true); // error now
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! What a shame that `Parameters` doesn't work like that.